# How should binary predicates be passed to a user-defined Boost.MPL algorithm?

Tags: c++, boost-mpl, template-meta-programming

Consider the following attempt at a Boost.MPL style metaprogramming version of `std::any_of`

```
    #include <iostream>                     // cout
    #include <type_traits>                  // is_base_of, is_pod
    #include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>          // apply
    #include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>           // fold
    #include <boost/mpl/lambda.hpp>         // lambda, _1, _2
    #include <boost/mpl/logical.hpp>        // and_, true_   
    #include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>         // vector

    template
    <
            typename Sequence,
            typename Pred
    >
    struct all_of
    :
            boost::mpl::fold<
                    Sequence,
                    boost::mpl::true_,
                    boost::mpl::lambda<
                            boost::mpl::and_<
                                    boost::mpl::_1,
                                    boost::mpl::apply< Pred, boost::mpl::_2 >
                            >
                    >
            >
    {};

    typedef int P1; typedef char P2; typedef float P3;

    typedef boost::mpl::vector<
            P1, P2, P3
    > pod_types;

    struct B {}; struct D1: B {}; struct D2: B {}; struct D3: B {};

    typedef boost::mpl::vector<
            D1, D2, D3
    > derived_types;

    int main() 
    {
            std::cout << (std::is_pod<P1>::value) << '\n';  // true
            std::cout << (std::is_pod<P2>::value) << '\n';  // true
            std::cout << (std::is_pod<P3>::value) << '\n';  // true       

            std::cout << (
                    all_of<
                            pod_types, 
                            std::is_pod< boost::mpl::_1 >                        
                    >::type::value  // true
            ) << '\n';

            std::cout << (std::is_base_of<B, D1>::value) << '\n';   // true
            std::cout << (std::is_base_of<B, D2>::value) << '\n';   // true
            std::cout << (std::is_base_of<B, D3>::value) << '\n';   // true

            std::cout << (
                    all_of<
                            derived_types, 
                            std::is_base_of< B, boost::mpl::_1 >    
                    >::type::value  // false (but should be true)
            ) << '\n';

            return 0;
    }
```

This prints out: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0. I.e., the final call to `all_of` with `std::is_base_of` passed as a predicate generates false. Why does this not work? Apperently, the base class `B` does not get properly bound to the predicate. How should I pass a binary predicate? Some combination of mpl::lambda or mpl::bind?

**UPDATE**

Based on Luc Touraille's excellent answer, here is the lambda-free solution to my question, with as an added bonus the compile-time versions of `none_of` and `any_of`

```
    template<typename Sequence, typename Pred>
    struct all_of
    :
            std::is_same< typename 
                    boost::mpl::find_if<
                            Sequence,
                            boost::mpl::not_<Pred>
                    >::type, typename 
                    boost::mpl::end<Sequence>::type
            >
    {};

    template<typename Sequence, typename Pred>
    struct none_of
    :
            all_of< Sequence, boost::mpl::not_< Pred > >
    {};

    template<typename Sequence, typename Pred>
    struct any_of
    :
            boost::mpl::not_< none_of< Sequence, Pred > >
    {};
```

Comment: It does not work in the first case either: if you add a non-pod in `pod_types`, you'll see that `all_of<pod_types, is_pod>` still returns true.

Comment: @Luc Touraille One can never test enough! I should have tested a negative outcome as well. Funny that unary predicates map to true and binary predicates map to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`find_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/find-if.html) instead of [`fold`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/fold.html):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/mpl/end.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/logical.hpp>

template
<
    typename Sequence,
    typename Pred
>
struct all_of
:
    std::is_same< typename
        boost::mpl::end< Sequence >::type, typename
        boost::mpl::find_if<
            Sequence,
            boost::mpl::not_< Pred >
        >::type
    >
{};
```

If you want to stick to [`fold`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/fold.html), you'll need to turn the predicate into a metafunction using [`lambda`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/lambda.html) before invoking it, to [protect](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/protect.html) the arguments:

```
boost::mpl::apply< typename
    boost::mpl::lambda< Pred >::type,
    boost::mpl::_2
>
```

However, you'll note that this won't work either. I'm not sure why exactly, I think it is related to [this discussion on the Boost mailing list](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2005/11/96171.php). Apparently, there is an issue with the arity of `apply` which is greater than the one supported by `lambda`. Anyway, a simple workaround is to use [`apply1`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/apply.html) instead of `apply`. Here is the full solution:

```
template
<
        typename Sequence,
        typename Pred
>
struct all_of
  : boost::mpl::fold<
        Sequence,
        boost::mpl::true_,
        boost::mpl::and_<
            boost::mpl::_1,
            boost::mpl::apply1< typename
                boost::mpl::lambda< Pred >::type,
                boost::mpl::_2
            >
        >
    >
{};
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Wouldn't it still be convenient to also have a `mpl::lambda` wrapping the placeholders inside the `mpl::and_` in the above code? Just in case you want to pass the `all_of` itself in a lambda expression? Or is this best done by outside callers?

Comment: Hum, I'm don't think this is necessary.As it is, `all_of` is a binary metafunction like any other, that can be used either with arguments or with placeholders. As far as I can tell, there is no risk of conflicting placeholders. I'm not completely sure about this, perhaps @JoelFalcou could confirm? (Hi Joel, btw!)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem you had was similar to the one described in [this thread](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2012/01/189614.php), namely nested placeholder expressions. Indeed, the instantiation of `all_of` with `is_pod` was equivalent to `fold< pod_types, true_, and_< _1, apply< is_pod< _1 >, _2 > > >`. The two `_1` was not meant to refer to the same arguments, hence the need to protect `is_pod< _1 >` with `lambda`.

Comment: If you create a placeholder expression with the last version of `all_of` I gave, and invoke it (e.g. `typedef all_of< _1, _2 > all_of_lambda; bool b = apply< all_of_lambda, pod_types, is_pod< _1 > >::type::value;`), you don't have any problem and obtain the good result. I must admit that I don't really understand why, though...

Comment: Sometimes I feel using Boost.MPL is walking on a tight mountain ledge: there's a beautiful view into the valley below, but put one step wrong... :-)

Comment: After a bit more reflection, I think there is no issue in the case described above because `all_of` *inherits* from `fold`: they are not the same type. Hence, `all_of< _1, _2 >` is *not* the same as `fold< _1, true_, and_< _1, apply1< lambda< _2 >::type, _2 > > >` (which would obviously won't work). It would be interesting to check the behavior when using C++11 template aliases.

Comment: I tested on GCC 4.7, it works with template aliases as well. I'm still a bit lost here :/! If you find more information, feel free to share :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the predicate into a lambda or _1 will be interpreted as the first level of calls of the fold instead of the first parameter to be passed to Pred. mpl::lambda is what you need

Comment: Where should a lambda be inserted? I tried both at the call site, and in the definition of all_of, but no success. And why does the unary predicate is_pod work as it is, even with a _1 passed as a parameter?